# Nested Databinding to Gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, binding

I'm trying to databind nested items onto my Gridview.  I had no problems for the top level items, only those that are nested (subject names) I was not able to access it.  Here's my code currently looks like.

studentSearch.xaml.cs

```
public class StudentSearchData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string studentName;
public string StudentName
{
    get
    {
        return studentName;
    }
    set
    {
        if (studentName != value)
        {
            studentName = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("StudentName");
        }
    }
}

public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
}

public class Subject
{
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

studentSearch.Xaml

```
<GridView Name="studentGridView" ItemSource="{Binding StudentName">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
     <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>

 <DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding studentName}" Grid.Row="0">
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Row="0">
   </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</GridView>
```

The error message I got was this when trying to access the Subject Name

> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Name' property not found on 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Studies.API.StudentSearchData , Studies, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'. BindingExpression: Path='Name' DataItem='System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Studies.API.StudentSearchData, Name, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.Run' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Answer (score 0):

Your GridView is using ItemSource 'StudentName'. Try to change it to StudentSearchData and on the XAML, since Subject is a list, you need to access it by calling it Subject.Name